# <select> within <a href> that I don't want to execute the link

Tags: html

I have a table wrapped in an a href so if they click anywhere in the table, a link will get executed.

My problem is that the table also has a select dropdown list and I don't want the link to execute if they click on the select element.

I've tried ending the a href before the select and starting again after the select but that doesn't work.

```
<a href="#" id="modifyPrefs" style="text-decoration:none;color:black">
<table class="formtable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option></option>
          <c:forEach items="${allPrefs.Siblings}" var="s">
            <option>${s.lastName}</option>
          </c:forEach>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you might want to look into javascript's `return false;`

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` will help if you're using the jQuery library

Comment: i have an idea, anyway could you provide code and jsfiddle?

Comment: Why is the entire table a link? What happens when you click it? Depending on that, there may be a better implementation that solves your problem.

Comment: Yeah, have to agree with @Llepwryd - there's no reason the entire table has to be a link.

Comment: when clicked, it shows a model popup where they can edit what is displayed, I thought I was being slick

Comment: Most programming problems happen when someone thinks they are "being slick."  Just add a click handler to the table - no reason to wrap it in an anchor.

Answer (score 1):

Putting whole table into href not make any sense.why not you put only header part of table into href.

OR

Just add simple edit button any by clicking that go to your url for edit.

HTML :

```
<button id='button-id'>Edit</button>
```

JQuery Code :

```
$('#button-id').click(function() { window.location.pathname = '/yoururl'; });
```

Comment: ya now I'm thinking a little icon in the upper-left will be better